# How to call MEL expression while invoking the key value with key from properties file in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

I have properties as below

```
path.order=/order
path.address=/address
```

Usually we will use ${path.order} to get the key value. I want to pass the type(order or address) dynamically to get the key value. Like below

```
${path.#[flowVars.type]}
```

I tired with above expression. It did not work. can you please help on this to prepare and get the key dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved using dataweave function. I am posting a snippet.
I tried concatenating withing the final dw expression, but it didn't work. Let me know if this fulfills your requirements.

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="type1" value="address"/>
            <add-message-property key="type2" value="object"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
<message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
     <add-message-property key="property1" value="#['path.' + flowVars.type1]"/>
     <add-message-property key="property2" value="#['path.' + flowVars.type2]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
<logger message="#[dw('p(flowVars.property1)')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

I have written a post on this [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-generate-property-key-at-run-time), as well.

Comment: I have to call the property key in http path

Comment: So you can paste the MEL #[dw('p(flowVars.property1)')] in the HTTP Requester configuration. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dictionary defined in my variables

```
var.dictionary=#[['key':'value', 'key': 'value']]
```

Then in my Dataweave I reference it and pass a key to it

```
node: flowVars.var.dictionary[payload01.key]
```

So (unfortunately untested) your example should have a variable:

```
var.dictionary=#[['order':'/order', 'address': '/address']]
```

And reference it as

```
flowVars.var.dictionary[#[flowVars.type]]
```

So it should look like:

```
<logger message="#[path.#flowVars.var.dictionary[#[flowVars.type]]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Access .property file by inserting following code.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="smtp.properties"/>
```

---

And Use it like this.

```
<logger message="${propertyFromFile}" doc:name="System Property Set in Property File"/>
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D95iw_ny8J4

Answer (score 0):

```
<set-variable variableName="type" value="order" doc:name="Variable"/>

    <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[flowVars.propertyName='path.'+flowVars.type;
    flowVars.propertyValue =dw("p(flowVars.propertyName)");]]></expression-component>

<logger message="#[flowVars.propertyValue]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```